# Inserting a row from a desktop c# app to a web based MySQL database

Tags: c#, php, mysql

I have a c# desktop applicationunsuccessfully attempting to programmatically insert a row into a web based MySQL database.  I need help to resolve this problem.

On the web end, I am using a web page with form containing the columns to be inserted.  The submission of the form goes to a PHP file that inserts the row from the posted data.  The page/form is as follows, and the insert works when I manually submit from the web.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insertrow.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="Id"><br>
<input type="text" name="Name"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

At the desktop, I am using WebRequest to post the data to the form.  This is the c# code that I copied from MSDN:

```
private static void UploadRow(int myId, string myName)
{
    // Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/myform.html");
    // Set the Method property of the request to POST.
    request.Method = "POST";
    // Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
    string postData = "Id=" + myId
                    + "&Name=" + myName;
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    // Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    // Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    // Get the request stream.
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    // Write the data to the request stream.
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    // Close the Stream object.
    dataStream.Close();
    // Get the response.
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    // Display the status.
    Console.WriteLine("Post Status=" + ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
    // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
    // Read the content.
    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // Display the content.
    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    // Clean up the streams.
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
}
```

When I run this, the post status is "OK" and the responseFromServer seems to be the HTML source of the page. Yet, nothing is inserted to the database. I am wodering if I'm missing the whoe point of how to use WebRequest.  I can't find any answers to this problem online.  I woud appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about the `c#` part, but maybe that `OK` is just the response, something like `200`? Can you post the php part that reads the form?Maybe it's checking for `isset($_POST['submit']..` or something like that

Comment: You may to send the submit button as well in the pist as parameter as submit=submit, depending on how the php code looks like.

Comment: Note, is the page correct? You are using `WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/myform.html");` Shouldn't it be a `php` page? (Yeah, I know this might be just when posting the question, but it's worth checking...)